# Angular 12 multiple sub card components changes apply only to first card component

Tags: html, angular

There's a problem that i'm facing with multiple card component instances.

In the page that i'm building, there are 5 goal card components, each of them having 5 sliders and a program logic that calculates average of 5 range values and dynamically change value at number spinner area on a single card component. Also changed range values are being dynamically shown on text area above individual ranges.

The problem is, my code applies "only" to first card component. Only values of first card is changing dynamically. 2,3,4 and 5th card components aren't responsive. When i change sliders i want the values inside span areas of every component to change. It's only working for first card component but other ones aren't responding. As you can see below on code, I generated 5 card row instances of goal-card.component.

I kinda know why that's happening (it's most likely because of getElementById() function and having same id's on multiple component instances. But I don't know how can I solve this without referencing Id's. It seems like it's impossible to define distinct id's for different instances of the same sub-component. I thought of assigning different id's to every "app-goal-card" component and then call the range instances referencing them but it's against Javascript rules i guess. Any help will be appreciated. How to fix this and make all components responsive (instead of just first rendered one)?

Html code where i call multiple sub-components is below:

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="card-container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap overflow-auto" id="card-row">
    <div class="col-2.5" style="padding-left: 5px;">
      <app-goal-card [id]="1"></app-goal-card>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-2.5" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <app-goal-card [id]="2"></app-goal-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2.5" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <app-goal-card></app-goal-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2.5" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <app-goal-card></app-goal-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2.5" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <app-goal-card></app-goal-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see i'm calling sub-component 5 times.

On below you can find a snippet where i dynamically get range value and print it to span area as percent value.

goal-card.component.html:

```
<div class="text-left" style="font-size: smaller">
          <span id="range1text">50</span> % growth in Market
        </div>
        <input
          type="range"
          class="form-range"
          id="customRange1"
          style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; width: 220px"
          value="50"
          oninput="document.getElementById('range1text').innerText = document.getElementById('customRange1').value;
        document.getElementById('number-spinner').value =
        (parseInt(document.getElementById('customRange1').value) + 
        parseInt(document.getElementById('customRange2').value) + 
        parseInt(document.getElementById('customRange3').value) + 
        parseInt(document.getElementById('customRange4').value) + 
        parseInt(document.getElementById('customRange5').value)) / 5"
        />
```

Comment: You should look into the `@Input` decorator if you want to pass data into your components. Take a look here, see if it helps you: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I know these concepts and I don't want to pass data into my component. Data are already being processed in my component. I just want to distinct elements in different sub component instances. At the moment if i change range value only first card component is working properly. I want to make others work too.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu i solved this problem by using "@ViewChild" annotation and manipulating elements inside .ts class instead of getElementById(). Thanks anyways.